# how to save an images current location to prevent a subsequent animation moving the image back to centre - swift

Tags: swift

I have a rotateArt function that rotates a UIImage - my problem is when this function is called following a pan gesture the image snaps back to the views centre. I would like it to rotate around its current centre.

I have tried assigning a variable to hold its current centre but that did not work. What am I missing?

Thanks

```
extension MainViewController {
    
    func imageCheck() {
        pickedImage != nil ? addPainting() : print("image did not load")
    }
    
    func addPainting() {
        pickedImageView = UIImageView(image: pickedImage)
        pickedImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        pickedImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(pickedImageView)
        pickedImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pickedImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userPickedRoom.centerXAnchor),
            pickedImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userPickedRoom.centerYAnchor, constant: -50),
            pickedImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
            pickedImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
        ])
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
        pickedImageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinch))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
        addShadow()
    }
    
    @objc func handlePan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
        guard let gestureView = sender.view else {return}
        gestureView.center = CGPoint(x: gestureView.center.x + translation.x, y: gestureView.center.y + translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
    }
    
    @objc func handlePinch(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        guard sender.view != nil else { return }
        if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
            pickedImageView.transform = (pickedImageView.transform.scaledBy(x: sender.scale, y: sender.scale))
            sender.scale = 1.0
        }
    }
    
    func rotateArt()  { // pickedImageView.center returns to view.center when this functinon is called.
        UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.pickedImageView.transform = self.pickedImageView.transform.rotated(by: .pi / 2)
        })
    }
    
    func addShadow() {
        pickedImageView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        pickedImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        pickedImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.1, height: 0.5)
        pickedImageView.layer.shadowRadius = 1
        pickedImageView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        pickedImageView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is these lines:

```
pickedImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate
```

You cannot position `pickedImageView` using constraints and *also* animate it by changing its `center` (as you do during the pan gesture).

Constraints are one thing. Frames/centers are a different thing. They are *opposites*. You have created a conflict here: you say one thing by changing the center during the pan, but the constraints say something else (they still want to put the image view where you told them to put it).

You need to resolve that conflict. The easiest way is not to use constraints at all, but there are other ways.

Comment: Oh wow yes thank you for that! I was using the constraints so that the image loaded in the right position. I will delete the constraints and instead do the same using Frames/Centers.